# Where to define proxy environment variables for firefox started via desktop links in lxde/debian9?

Tags: debian, environment-variables, firefox, lxde, http-proxy

I'm trying to set the system-wide http_proxy environment variables (automated by a shell script) in such a way, that firefox uses them when executed from the LXDE start menu for all users.

So far I set the environment variables http_proxy and https_proxy in /etc/profile.d/99proxy.sh and in /etc/bash.bashrc for login-shell and non-login-shell respectively. If I execute firefox in a non-login shell, firefox uses the proxy. If I execute firefox in a login-shell, firefox uses the proxy also. But if I click on the link in the LXDE start menu, firefox appears to have the environment variables not available.

The first questions would be: In what context does LXDE execute firefox (or other applications)?
The second question is: Where does a program executed by LXDE get its environment variables from?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The right file for the proxy environment variables is /etc/environment.